# Event Delegation vs. Closure/For Loop? Code comparison provided? Which is a better style?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I was wondering if it was better to go with a closure and a for loop or an event delegation with a hacky `.split()` array access. Code is provided below:

```
<div id="1">
<button id="btn-0">Button 1!</button>
<button id="btn-1">Button 2!</button>
<button id="btn-2">Button 3!</button>
</div>

<!-- <script type="text/javascript">
    var prizes = ['A Unicorn!', 'A Hug!', 'Fresh Laundry!'];
    for (var btnNum = 0; btnNum < prizes.length; btnNum++) {
        // for each of our buttons, when the user clicks it...
        document.getElementById('btn-' + btnNum).onclick = function(frozenBtnNum){
            return function() {
                // tell her what she's won!
                alert(prizes[frozenBtnNum]);
            };
        }(btnNum);
    }
</script> -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    var prizes = ['A Unicorn!', 'A Hug!', 'Fresh Laundry!'];
    document.getElementById("1").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "BUTTON") {
            // List item found!  Output the ID!
            alert(prizes[e.target.id.split("-")[1]]);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Generally speaking I prefer for loops if jQuery isn't available.

Comment: Neither, I would rather use the data-* attributes to store information, and use the [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) to get the information.

Comment: Give the buttons a *value* (or *data-*) attribute and use that instead of ID. Whether you put a listener on each button or delegate to a parent is a matter of preference in design. What are your criteria for "better"?

Comment: @PatrickEvans @RobG Would you comment (or provide a resource) as to why you would use `data-*`? I'm new to JS design and it seems like storing data in the DOM conflicts with a "separation of concerns" philosophy.

Comment: `with a hacky .split() array access` why is it hacky?

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert but no one has answered. I believe the former method (using closure) would have a greater impact on performance, since you are adding event listeners to a greater number of elements (see this [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/click-perf) test that shows performance as the number of elements increases).

The latter method (event delegation) only has one listener, so it won't suffer the same perf hit. From the comments it appears that others have suggested using the `data-*` attribute (though they didn't say why?), which is similar to this method as well. That said, you would be storing data in the DOM, and based on my (limited) experience that is generally not good design, because then your logic becomes dependent on your UI.